# Printing aligned nested dictionary with keys as rows

Tags: python, python-3.7

Preface: I do not have pandas, or itertools and have very limited modules in this environment so I need to keep this as pythonic as possible. Im using 3.7.3 on Buster debian.

I have a nested dictionary called `all_dicts` that has:

- All keys will appear in the same order with the same name across all dictionaries (e.g. all dictionaries will have "Authors" and it will be first)
- Every dictionary will have a key/value pairing (e.g. if there is no ISBN yet it will have a '0' value)
- All keys/values are strings
- All values are expected vary in length (maybe not year, not for a while at least)

The dict of dicts:

```
all_dicts = {
     'dict_0': {'Author(s)': 'Ian Flemming', 'Year': '1956', 'Title': 'Diamonds are Forever', 'surname': 'Flemming', 'ISBN Number will go here': '9781612185460'},
     'dict_1': {'Author(s)': 'Jules Verne', 'Year': '1870', 'Title': '20,000 Leagues Under the Sea', 'surname': 'Verne', 'ISBN Number will go here': '0451531698'}}
```

The Goal:
What I am attempting to print (the #### doesnt have to be present)

```
#######                     dict_0                 dict_1
Authors                     Ian Flemming           Jules Verne
Year                        1956                   1870
Title                       Diamonds are Forever   20,000 Leagues Under the Sea
Surname                     Flemming               Verne
ISBN Number will go here    9781612185460          0451531698
```

What I have gathered and pieced together (mostly from other SO pots) so far
Gathering the "rows"

```
row_label = (max(all_dicts.values(), key=len))
for i in row_label:
  print(i)
```

Results in:

```
Author(s)
Year
Title
surname
ISBN Number will go here
```

Attempting to loop through to get "columns"

```
for j in all_dicts:
  print(j + "\n" + "\n".join(map(str, [all_dicts[j][q] for q in all_dicts[j]])))
  print("======")
```

Results in

```
dict_0
Ian Flemming
1956
Diamonds are Forever
Flemming
9781612185460
======
dict_1
Jules Verne
1870
20,000 Leagues Under the Sea
Verne
0451531698
======
```

So far I've got each component (rows and columns) individually and here is where I am struggling to figure out how to piece these together.

```
def get_keys(my_dict):
    keys = list(my_dict.keys())
    keys = my_dict[keys[0]].keys()
    keys = list(keys)
    return keys
print("\t\t\t" + "\t\t".join(all_dicts))
for key in get_keys(all_dicts):
    print(key + " " + "\t".join(str(all_dicts[j].get(key)) for j in all_dicts), end="\n")
```

Results in the desired style, just with horrible formatting/spacing.

```
            dict_0      dict_1
Author(s) Ian Flemming  Jules Verne
Year 1956   1870
Title Diamonds are Forever  20,000 Leagues Under the Sea
surname Flemming    Verne
ISBN Number will go here 9781612185460  0451531698
```

Another attempt.

```
print("\t\t\t" + "\t\t".join(all_dicts))
row_label = (max(all_dicts.values(), key=len))
for i in row_label:
  print(i + "\t\t" + "\t".join(str(all_dicts[j].get(i)) for j in all_dicts))
```

Results in

```
            dict_0      dict_1
Author(s)       Ian Flemming    Jules Verne
Year        1956    1870
Title       Diamonds are Forever    20,000 Leagues Under the Sea
surname     Flemming    Verne
ISBN Number will go here        9781612185460   0451531698
```

How can I go about tabularizing this given nested dictionaries?

Comment: You do have itertools, it's in the standard library.

Comment: @mkrieger1 you are correct - I really am unsure where I got the idea that I did not have itertools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue at the end is to print strings of different sizes into a same size output

You can't only use `\t` or a space, to separate the things, you need string formatting

```
def format_row(row_header: str, values):
    return "".join(f"{item:30s}" for item in [row_header, *values])


print(format_row('', all_dicts))

for key in all_dicts['dict_0']:
    values = [value[key] for value in all_dicts.values()]
    print(format_row(key, values))
```

Comment: This scales nicely if/when all_dicts grows to more than the given 2 examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way without any additional library.
I combined the dicts and printed them (without joining each row to a string) by string formatting with a fixed width.
Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) how to format strings.

```
all_dicts = {
     'dict_0': {'Author(s)': 'Ian Flemming', 'Year': '1956', 'Title': 'Diamonds are Forever', 'surname': 'Flemming', 'ISBN Number will go here': '9781612185460'},
     'dict_1': {'Author(s)': 'Jules Verne', 'Year': '1870', 'Title': '20,000 Leagues Under the Sea', 'surname': 'Verne', 'ISBN Number will go here': '0451531698'}}
d = {}
for key in all_dicts:
    for k,v in all_dicts[key].items():
        if k not in d:
            d[k] = [v]
        else:
            d[k].append(v)
print(d)


print("{0:<50} {1:<50} {2:<50}".format("###", "dict1", "dict2")) # formatting with "str.format()"
for k, v in d.items():
    print(f"{k:<50} {v[0]:<50} {v[1]:<50}") # formatting with f-strings
```

Output:

```
# d
{'Author(s)': ['Ian Flemming', 'Jules Verne'], 
'Year': ['1956', '1870'], 
'Title': ['Diamonds are Forever', '20,000 Leagues Under the Sea'], 
'surname': ['Flemming', 'Verne'], 
'ISBN Number will go here': ['9781612185460', '0451531698']}

# print statement

###                                      dict1                                    dict2                                   
Author(s)                                Ian Flemming                             Jules Verne                             
Year                                     1956                                     1870                                    
Title                                    Diamonds are Forever                     20,000 Leagues Under the Sea            
surname                                  Flemming                                 Verne                                   
ISBN Number will go here                 9781612185460                            0451531698
```

Comment: I will certainly look into the output formatting - that seems to be the key I was missing. Combining the dictionaries did not cross my mind, thank you for the explanations!